# Quick Python Script to see if float x ∈ range without very small steps

Tags: python, math, mathematical-optimization

I have float/decimal values like 2,4378472348237483274 etc.
and for some instructions there must be a condition for these numbers.
Condition must be:   ∈ (range)
But for Python, 2 is in (1,3,1) but 2,1231837 is not in (1,3,1) because of the step. I don't know how to set range without steps...
So my idea is to code a little custom range that only looks at the unit.
For example: 2,47234723278 
So it looks at "2" (unit) and confirm that it is in a range (1,3).

For now, I have a very slow script that has a very little step... not performant as you guess.

So either you help me building a range without any steps (but computationally not possible, I guess) or you help me building a custom range with a script that makes it only look at the integer part.

Example:

213,4

Only look at 213.

Thanks a lot

Comment: Are you asking how to check if 2,47234723278 belongs to the interval from 1 to 3? If so, you can simply check that it is greater than 1 and less than 3.

Answer (score 0):

Well you could just check the borders of your range

```
low = 1.0
high = 3.0

def inrange(x):
    if x<=high and x >= low:
       return true
    else:
       return false
```

Or you could cast into an integer, which will always give you the lower whole number of your float:

```
int(213.4) = 213
```